# Windows Phone .Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke affect process

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing one chat application in windows phone. I am using `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method to update the UI, but at the time of using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` the screen will struck. How to solve this or any way to update the UI without stuck?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the dispatcher then you will execute the given code in the UI thread. And while you execute code in the UI thread, the UI is stuck. There's no way around that, so you must make sure to execute only the absolute minimum amount of code in the UI thread. The common pattern is to retrieve/compute the data in a background thread, then switch to the UI only to update the controls. The `BackgroundWorker` class is a convenient helper to reach this result.

Comment: thanks kookiz, how to use Backgroundworker class for insert data to isolated storage because i am going to insert lot of data continuously ..